# Timestamps in mod inbox on /admin/users/{id}/post-comments are bold

Tags: bug, design, moderator-tools

I've probably just found one of the least consequential bugs ever, but it may indicate something deeper so I'm reporting anyway. Compare a 'normal' mod inbox:

[image]

To the inbox on [`/admin/users/{id}/post-comments`](https://stackoverflow.com/admin/users/1849664/post-comments):

[image]

The timestamps are bold on one, not bold on the other. Doesn't bug me enough to *really* matter, but it might signal something deeper with how CSS styles are being handled and separated throughout the different parts of a page (rogue inline style somewhere?)

Comment: Red inline style? I think you might have meant rogue ;)

Comment: @ArtOfCode I must be missing something here :P

Comment: Edited it. You had typed rouge, and I think you meant rogue.

Comment: @undo *[Rouge is a pinkish color or a reddish powder](http://grammarist.com/spelling/rogue-rouge/)* - I agree it's very easily missed though and I had no idea of that until now... ;)

Comment: Well that makes more sense. TIL.